# Icons for MO/metaMO in community list changed?

Tags: bug, design, site-changes, top-bar

I notice that in the community list under the SE hamburger in the top right, the icons for MO and for meta have changed:

[image: screenshot of list of communities]

clearly having the MO logo attached to meta.math.SE is an issue, but we are also seeing 'MAT' for MO and 'ME' for math.SE.

What's going on?

Comment: I don't see it now. It may have been a temporary issue.  It's apparently a pretty normal temporary glitch when Stack Exchange updates their sprite sheets (as for the creation of a new site).

Comment: @Buzz I can still see it now.

Comment: I don't see it. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: MSE: [Stack Exchange site icons displaying incorrectly in Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379726/stack-exchange-site-icons-displaying-incorrectly-in-hot-network-questions)

Comment: Is this consistent across browsers, devices, and operating systems?

Comment: No. On my Android tablet, but with same browser as on my Mac, things are fine.

Comment: OK, it seems to be fixed now. I tried force refreshing every now and then over several days, but now with no effort on my part it's back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved, I just needed to wait until the SE system and my browser got their act together.